# Regex named-capture groups in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

I need to extract ICD 9 values from a requirements document.  The ICD 9 values could be individual codes like `V91.19` or ranges `441.00-441`.  For example:

```
    4. Peripheral vascular disorders - ICD-9-CM codes: 440.0-440.9, 441.00-441.9, 442.0-442.9, 443.1-443.9, 447.1, 557.1, 557.9, V43.4, V91.19, V9000, V91, M8440/0
```

Ultimately, the goal is to use these values in a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ICD9 
WHERE (
        (CODE BETWEEN '440.0' AND '440.9')
        OR (CODE BETWEEN '441.00' AND '441.9')
        ...
        OR CODE IN ('447.1', '557.1', '557.9', 'V43.4', 'V91.19', 'V9000', 'V91', 'M8440/0') 
      )
```

This regex:

```
/[A-Z]?[0-9]+[\.\/]?[0-9]*/g
```

matches:

- the individual ICD 9 values (`447.1`)
- the starting and ending values of the range (`440.0`-`440.9`)
- `4.` and ICD-`9`-CM - not desirable

How do I need to modify my regex to:

- create a capture group for the individual values?
- create a capture group for the range values?
- exclude the undesirables?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
[A-Z]?[0-9]+[\.\/]?(?=\d)[0-9]*
```

where

- **`(?=\d)`** The **positive lookahead** - Assert that the regex can be matched only if a digit [0-9]

Same results is if your remove the optional **`*`** part of the last digit like and replace it with **`+`**:

```
[A-Z]?[0-9]+[\.\/]?[0-9]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/nK3zB3/2

About the ranges and groups I think it could something like:

```
(([A-Z]?[0-9]+[\.\/]?[0-9]+)[-]*(([A-Z]?[0-9]+[\.\/]?[0-9]+))?)
```

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nK3zB3/4)**

Comment: Both address #3.  I think I need a capture group that references another capture group to fix #2.

Comment: Ideally, there would be one set of matches for the range and another set for the individuals.  I'm guessing two regexps.  Moreover, is there a way to use names to keep things DRY?